# nested loop of columns and rows..in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How to introduce a nested for loops of rows/colummns in Storedprocedure- am very new to stored procedure :( .. I have two tables with same columns. am trying to iterate the table and using their values.

```
For Each row in Table1

   For Each row in Table2

      For Each Column
        'Here we are in a column Row intersection 
         my value = value of table1 + value of table 2.

      End loop 'Each Column

  End loop 'Each row in Table2'

End loop 'Each row in Table1'
```

Any help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide your table structures and example data/desired results so we can see what you are trying to do. SQL is set based / declarative not procedural.

Comment: agreed. this sounds like you just need a simple query

Answer (score 1):

you may consider a simple select to add the values like this:

```
select t1.value + t2.value as result
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.pk = t2.fk
```